# Roll overs in interactive pdfs for iPad—nothing is working

Tags: ipad, pdf, interactive, rollovers, rollover-effect

I'm having a problem with making roll overs work in an interactive pdf for iPad and mobile devices. I've spent hours looking for a resolution, but have found nothing for this specific issue...

What I have is sections in the document where the viewer can answer questions via check boxes. The check boxes work fine. However the check boxes for the incorrect answers trigger, on roll over, a 'pop-up' window that will nudge them to the correct answer. I have tried doing this through InDesign at the design stage and through Acrobat. Right now the functionality is primarily through Acrobat (seems to be closer to the end goal).

I'm not sure if it's as simple as a setting or what? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. More specific information can be given if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Adding some code to your post will help potential answerers provide a useful answer.

Comment: You cannot be sure that the application the reader is using can handle this. If you decide to throw every viewer available into a bin and call it "for iPad and mobile devices", then you're lowering the target to just about the bare bones of a PDF.  A simple one, at that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the "documentation" for the various PDF viewers for iOS, and see what they support.

Opposed to the Windows and OSX platforms, Adobe Reader for iOS (and Android) is mediocre at best, when it comes to JavaScript support (which is most likely the base for the rollovers). For iOS, the leader of the pack is PDFExpert by Readdle. With some luck, this PDF viewer may support what you want to accomplish.